# Turn on location services using code without user input

Tags: android, location, android-7.1-nougat, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on phone locator app and need turn on location automatically if off. The scenario is something like if phone is lost, location disabled and internet on, i can turn on the location remotely, find my phone. Need this to work for Android N and Oreo also. Can device administrator do the job or is there any other special permission which will allow me to enable/disable location without any user interaction? Not looking for any prompt from location manager.
If there isnt, is there any other way we can achieve same goal?

Comment: Your only hope would be device admin/owner APIs. Anything else would be a security flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this functionality can be achieved on pre-lollipop devices.

But post-lollipop or marshmallow, devices needs to allow the permissions.